# Lots of broken packages after I interrupted an update process

Tags: 12.04, dpkg

I use a VPS running Ubuntu 12.04 from myhosting.com, which I access only via ssh.

Yesterday I ran the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install lame build-essential libffi-dev
```

I let it run until I noticed a message asking me if certain mysql dbases should be removed "`after phpmyadmin was removed`". I panicked - as I didn't realize there would be a deletion of phpmydmin; and interrupted the process.
Since then I have had tons of broken packages and cannot install anything, as dkpg fails.

Below are the error messages I am getting when running `apt-get -f` install. Where should I start recovering the broken packages?

---

```
root@vps-1150506-19848:/# apt-get -f install  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree   
Reading state information... Done  
Correcting dependencies... Done    
The following extra packages will be installed:   
init-system-helpers initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-bin klibc-utils
libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libapt-pkg-perl libapt-pkg4.16 libc-dev-bin
libc6-dev libklibc lsb-base upstart
Suggested packages:
bash-completion glibc-doc graphviz upstart-monitor
The following NEW packages will be installed:
 libapt-pkg4.16
The following packages will be upgraded:
init-system-helpers initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-bin klibc-utils
 libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libapt-pkg-perl libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libklibc
lsb-base upstart
11 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1179 not upgraded.
48 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/3392 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2959 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
E: Could not open file descriptor -1
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/libc-dev-bin_2.21-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/initramfs-tools_0.120ubuntu3_all.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/upstart_1.13.2-0ubuntu14_amd64.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/init-system-helpers_1.23ubuntu3_all.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/initramfs-tools-bin_0.120ubuntu3_amd64.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/libklibc_2.0.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/klibc-utils_2.0.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/lsb-base_4.1+Debian11ubuntu8_all.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/libapt-pkg4.16_1.0.9.10ubuntu6_amd64.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl_0.04-3build1_amd64.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/libapt-pkg-perl_0.1.29build3_amd64.deb
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package libgcc1:amd64 (--configure):
package libgcc1:amd64 1:5.2.1-16ubuntu1 cannot be configured because libgcc1:i386 is at a different version (1:4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
dpkg: error processing package libc6:amd64 (--configure):
package libc6:amd64 2.21-0ubuntu4 cannot be configured because libc6:i386 is at a different version (2.19-0ubuntu6.3~ubuntu14.04.1~ppa1)
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of multiarch-support:
multiarch-support depends on libc6 (>= 2.3.6-2); however:
Package libc6:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package multiarch-support (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
libgcc1:amd64
libc6:amd64
multiarch-support

 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: 1179 not upgraded! shouldn't you run an upgrade before trying to install stuff

Answer (score 0):

You have some :i386 packages that should be installed as -i386:amd64 and not :i386

Run the following commands and please post any errors:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo dpkg -P libgcc1:i386 libc6:i386
sudo apt-get install libgcc1-i386 libc6-i386 
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

You might want to do a `dist-upgrade` but only run `dist-upgrade` if you know what you are doing!

Comment: Maybe OP needs the `:i386` packages?

Comment: @A.B. I'm not sure. Isn't that why the `-i386:amd64` versions are available? All I know is that there's a ppa version of `libc:i386` conflicting with multiarch and causing errors because for some reason, the `:amd64` counterpart isn't being installed. Maybe the ppa was removed?  Those builds are really old anyhow and there have been security updates since then that don't seem to have been applied so it's probably best to at least get rid of the existing version.

Comment: https://launchpad.net/~andrewrk/+archive/ubuntu/libgroove/+build/6444978